# How to fetch logged in user workphoto from company active directory using spring boot + spring ldap and display the image in the user profile screen?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-ldap

I am working on a company internal web based application which need to use Spring Boot. The user will authenticate using windows credentials.
The application need to have a user profile page which will fetch the user details like below:

1. Display Name |
2. Email |
3. authorities |
4. Workphoto

Until now I am able to fetch the first three details and trying to fetch to workphoto from active directory which needs to be displayed on the user profile page.

The "InetOrgPerson" does not have the function to getWorkPhoto from user details populated from ldap. Pointers to some existing solutions would be much appreciated.

Below is my code:
1. SecurityConfiguration.java

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPersonContextMapper;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        logger.info("inside1");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**","/sb-admin/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        logger.info("inside2");

        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/static/**/*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
        httpSecurity.formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error").loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggerListener loggerListener() {
        return new LoggerListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
                "XXXXX.COM", "ldap://XXXXcorp.com:389/",
                "OU=Users,DC=XXXX,DC=com");

        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        provider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(sAMAccountName={0})(userPrincipalName={0})))");
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        logger.info("provider ::: " + provider);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(inetOrgPersonContextMapper());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public InetOrgPersonContextMapper inetOrgPersonContextMapper() {
        return new InetOrgPersonContextMapper();
    }

}
```

Below is controller code:
1. Controller.java

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPerson;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile;

@RestController
public class MainController {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MainController.class);
    private String username;

    /*
     * @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET) public
     * String home() { return "site.homepage"; }
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printWelcome(final ModelMap model) {
        logger.info("inside printWelcome");
        return new ModelAndView("site.homepage", "model", model);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user-profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showUserProfile(final ModelMap model) {
        logger.info("inside showUserProfile");
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            this.username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();

        } else {
            this.username = principal.toString();

        }
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        model.addAttribute("roomNumber",
                ((InetOrgPerson) principal).getRoomNumber());
        model.addAttribute("emailAddress",
                ((InetOrgPerson) principal).getMail());
        model.addAttribute("displayName",
                ((InetOrgPerson) principal).getDisplayName());
        model.addAttribute("employeeNumber",
                ((InetOrgPerson) principal).getEmployeeNumber());
        model.addAttribute("authorities", ((InetOrgPerson) principal)
                .getAuthorities().toString());
        model.addAttribute("otherDetails", ((InetOrgPerson) principal).getUid());
        return new ModelAndView("site.userprofile", "model", model);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(final ModelMap model) {
        logger.info("inside login");
        ModelAndView modelview = new ModelAndView();
        modelview.setViewName("site.login");

        return modelview;

    }



}
```

Comment: Ofcourse it doesn't as it only provides a common abstraction. Write an ldap based dao which fetches the needed data for you. Also why do you need the controller, there is nothing in there that you cannot already retrieve with the security namespace yourself.

Comment: I currently dont have a UI layer ready to use spring security tags. Could you please elaborate what is ldap based dao? I am new to spring ldap and learning. Any pointers to a useful source would be helpful.

Comment: what is there more to elaborate... Create a layer that used ldap (`LdapTemplate` for instance) and use that to obtain the needed information.